# Why does json.Unmarshal need a pointer to a map, if a map is a reference type?

Tags: json, go

I was working with `json.Unmarshal` and came across the following quirk. When running the below code, I get the error `json: Unmarshal(non-pointer map[string]string)`

```
func main() {
    m := make(map[string]string)
    data := `{"foo": "bar"}`
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IbHCz8i1r1)

Looking at the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) for `json.Unmarshal`, there is seemingly no indication that a pointer is required. The closest I can find is the following line

> Unmarshal parses the JSON-encoded data and stores the result in the value pointed to by v.

The lines regarding the protocol Unmarshal follows for maps are similarly unclear, as it makes no reference to pointers.

> To unmarshal a JSON object into a map, Unmarshal first establishes a map to use. If the map is nil, Unmarshal allocates a new map. Otherwise Unmarshal reuses the existing map, keeping existing entries. Unmarshal then stores key-value pairs from the JSON object into the map. The map's key type must either be a string, an integer, or implement encoding.TextUnmarshaler.

Why must I pass a pointer to json.Unmarshal, especially if maps are already reference types? I know that if I pass a map to a function, and add data to the map, the underlying data of the map will be changed (see [the following playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/O4th9aUvZT)), which means that it shouldn't matter if I pass a pointer to a map. Can someone clear this up?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As stated in the documentation:

> Unmarshal uses the inverse of the encodings that Marshal uses, allocating maps, slices, and pointers as necessary, with ...

`Unmarshal` may allocates the variable(map, slice, etc.). If we pass a `map` instead of *pointer* to a `map`, then the newly allocated `map` won't be visible to the caller. The following examples ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LHBEFiK_Hj)) demonstrates this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func mapFunc(m map[string]interface{}) {
    m = make(map[string]interface{})
    m["abc"] = "123"
}

func mapPtrFunc(mp *map[string]interface{}) {
    m := make(map[string]interface{})
    m["abc"] = "123"

    *mp = m
}

func main() {
    var m1, m2 map[string]interface{}
    mapFunc(m1)
    mapPtrFunc(&m2)

    fmt.Printf("%+v, %+v\n", m1, m2)
}
```

in which the output is:

```
map[], map[abc:123]
```

If the requirement says that a function/method may allocate a variable when necessary and the newly allocated variable need to be visible to the caller, the solution will be: (a) the variable must be in function's *return* statement **or** (b) the variable can be assigned to the function/method argument. Since in `go` *everything* is pass by value, in case of (b), the argument must be a *pointer*. The following diagram illustrates what happen in the above example:

[image: Illustration of variable allocation]

1. At first, both map `m1` and `m2` point to `nil`.
2. Calling `mapFunc` will copy the value pointed by `m1` to `m` resulting `m` will also point to `nil` map.
3. If in (1) the map already allocated, then in (2) the address of *underlying map data structure* pointed by `m1` (*not the address of `m1`*) will be copied to `m`. In this case both `m1` and `m` point to the same *map data structure*, thus modifying map items through `m1` will also be *visible* to `m`.
4. In the `mapFunc` function, new map is allocated and assigned to `m`. There is no way to assign it to `m1`.

In case of pointer:

1. When calling `mapPtrFunc`, the address of `m2` will be copied to `mp`.
2. In the `mapPtrFunc`, new map is allocated and assigned to `*mp` (not `mp`). Since `mp` is pointer to `m2`, assigning the new map to `*mp` will change the value pointed by `m2`. Note that the value of `mp` is unchanged, i.e. the address of `m2`.

Comment: I really like this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The other key part of the documentation is this:

> To unmarshal JSON into a pointer, Unmarshal first handles the case of
>   the JSON being the JSON literal null. In that case, Unmarshal sets the
>   pointer to nil. Otherwise, Unmarshal unmarshals the JSON into the
>   value pointed at by the pointer. If the pointer is nil, Unmarshal
>   allocates a new value for it to point to.

If Unmarshall accepted a map, it would have to leave the map in the same state whether the JSON were `null` or `{}`.  But by using pointers, there's now a difference between the pointer being set to `nil` and it pointing to an empty map.

Note that in order for Unmarshall to be able to "set the pointer to nil", you actually need to pass in a pointer to your map pointer:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    var m *map[string]string
    data := `{}`
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(m)

    data = `null`
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(m)

    data = `{"foo": "bar"}`
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

This outputs:

```
&map[]
<nil>
&map[foo:bar]
```

Comment: Yes, but what confuses me about that part of the documentation is that it makes reference to if a pointer were passed. However, it does not explain the necessity of using a pointer to the map. Regarding your explanation, wouldn't the following lines in the documentation cover the case you're talking about? "The JSON null value unmarshals into an interface, map, pointer, or slice by setting that Go value to nil. Because null is often used in JSON to mean “not present,” unmarshaling a JSON null into any other Go type has no effect on the value and produces no error."

Comment: Wouldn't that seem to indicate that a pointer isn't required? Specifically the language "slice, map, OR pointer" Sorry, I might be missing something.

Comment: That's referring to the thing pointed at by whatever pointer you pass in as `v`.  The very first line of the Unmarshal documentation is "Unmarshal parses the JSON-encoded data and stores the result in the value pointed to by v."  `v` has to be a pointer, and the source makes that very clear as well (https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/decode.go#L177).  You can pass in a pointer to an interface, a pointer to a map, a pointer to a pointer (as I did in my code here), etc.

Comment: You're of course right that one could create an Unmarshal function that mutates a map, but this is more consistent, and it allows things like setting map pointers to `nil`, and unmarshalling into things like ints (`var n int; data = "1"; json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &n)`). By having `v` always be a pointer, possibly to another pointer, possible to a reference type like a map, possibly to a non-reference type like an int, things are consistent.

Comment: In any case, this is how they chose to do it, and I personally find the documentation clear enough.  But perhaps a sentence of clarification would be a useful addition.

Comment: Awesome. I do like the note about consistency. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your viewpoint is no different than saying "a slice is nothing but a pointer". Slices (and maps) use pointers to make them lightweight, yes, but there are still more things that make them work. A slice contains info about its length and capacity for example.

As for why this happens, from a code perspective, the last line of `json.Unmarshal` calls `d.unmarshal()`, which executes the code in [lines 176-179 of decode.go](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/decode.go?s=6444:6569#L176). It basically says "if the value isn't a pointer, or is `nil`, return an `InvalidUnmarshalError`."

The docs could probably be clearer about things, but consider a couple of things:

1. How would the JSON `null` value be assigned to the map as `nil` if you don't pass a pointer to the map? If you require the ability to modify the map itself (rather than the items in the map), then it makes sense to pass a pointer to the item that needs modified. In this case, it's the map.
2. Alternately, suppose you passed a `nil` map to `json.Unmarshal`. Values will be unmarshaled as necessary after the code `json.Unmarshal` uses eventually calls the equivalent of `make(map[string]string)`. However, you still have a `nil` map in your function because your map pointed to nothing. There's no way to fix this other than to pass a pointer to the map.

However, let's say there was no need to pass the address of your map because "it's already a pointer", and you've already initialized the map, so it's not `nil`. What happens then? Well, if I bypass the test in the lines I linked earlier by changing line 176 to read `if rv.Kind() != reflect.Map && rv.Kind() != reflect.Ptr || rv.IsNil() {`, then this can happen:

```
`{"foo":"bar"}`: false map[foo:bar]
`{}`: false map[]
`null`: panic: reflect: reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value [recovered]
    panic: interface conversion: string is not error: missing method Error

goroutine 1 [running]:
json.(*decodeState).unmarshal.func1(0xc420039e70)
    /home/kit/jstest/src/json/decode.go:172 +0x99
panic(0x4b0a00, 0xc42000e410)
    /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/panic.go:489 +0x2cf
reflect.flag.mustBeAssignable(0x15)
    /usr/lib/go/src/reflect/value.go:228 +0xf9
reflect.Value.Set(0x4b8b00, 0xc420012300, 0x15, 0x4b8b00, 0x0, 0x15)
    /usr/lib/go/src/reflect/value.go:1345 +0x2f
json.(*decodeState).literalStore(0xc420084360, 0xc42000e3f8, 0x4, 0x8, 0x4b8b00, 0xc420012300, 0x15, 0xc420000100)
    /home/kit/jstest/src/json/decode.go:883 +0x2797
json.(*decodeState).literal(0xc420084360, 0x4b8b00, 0xc420012300, 0x15)
    /home/kit/jstest/src/json/decode.go:799 +0xdf
json.(*decodeState).value(0xc420084360, 0x4b8b00, 0xc420012300, 0x15)
    /home/kit/jstest/src/json/decode.go:405 +0x32e
json.(*decodeState).unmarshal(0xc420084360, 0x4b8b00, 0xc420012300, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/kit/jstest/src/json/decode.go:184 +0x224
json.Unmarshal(0xc42000e3f8, 0x4, 0x8, 0x4b8b00, 0xc420012300, 0x8, 0x0)
    /home/kit/jstest/src/json/decode.go:104 +0x148
main.main()
    /home/kit/jstest/src/jstest/main.go:16 +0x1af
```

Code leading to that output:

```
package main

// Note "json" is the local copy of the "encoding/json" source that I modified.
import (
    "fmt"
    "json"
)

func main() {
    for _, data := range []string{
        `{"foo":"bar"}`,
        `{}`,
        `null`,
    } {
        m := make(map[string]string)
        fmt.Printf("%#q: ", data)
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), m); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(m == nil, m)
        }
    }
}
```

The key is this bit here:

```
reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value
```

Because you passed a copy of the map, it's unaddressable (i.e. it has a temporary address or even no address from the low-level machine perspective). I know of one way around this (`x := new(Type)` followed by `*x = value`, except using the `reflect` package), but it doesn't actually solve the problem; you're creating a local pointer that can't be returned to the caller and using it instead of your original storage location!

So now try a pointer:

```
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), m); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(m == nil, m)
        }
```

Output:

```
`{"foo":"bar"}`: false map[foo:bar]
`{}`: false map[]
`null`: true map[]
```

Now it works. Bottom line: use pointers if the object itself may be modified (and the docs say it might be, e.g. if `null` is used where an object or array (map or slice) is expected.

Comment: Could you please clarify the concept of being unaddressable here? I wrote a test to look at the concept of addressability of copies of maps, and I seem to be able to get the address of it just fine. https://play.golang.org/p/leUodSrTxG

Comment: @ollien You're creating a pointer to `a` in that function, which means the compiler makes `a` addressable. By default, any function parameters are unaddressable, including method receivers. If you create a pointer to an existing object, the pointer itself is unaddressable, but the object it points to is addressable because it has an address. See a modified version of your example that uses reflection at https://play.golang.org/p/CR_3WSkm_V . The [`CanAddr` method of `reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.CanAddr) returns whether a value is addressable or not.

Comment: Note that `reflect.ValueOf(foo)` results in the `CanAddr` method of the returned `reflect.Value` return `false`. Again, `foo` was passed to `reflect.ValueOf` by value. `reflect.ValueOf(&foo)` will result in `&foo` being unaddressable still, but `foo` (`reflect.Indirect(rv)` or `rv.Elem()`) is now addressable.

Comment: I highly recommend reading [The Laws of Reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection) to aid you in your understanding of how reflection works.